# Beanstalk / Git - Staying Centralized?

Tags: git, version-control, ftp

I would like to start a centralized repo as described here http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/intro-to-version-control.html#types-of-vcs - want to start a little simpler to introduce everyone on my team to versioning without delving into distributed systems quite yet. I'll be the first to admit I'm new to these concepts after years of direct FTP access to backup/edit/upload code.

I'm hoping to have one central version of the code with all users' edits being tracked, allowing easy audits of changes and reverts when necessary. It would also be really nice if there wasn't the requirement to clone the entire repo locally onto each new computer that'll be doing edits - before any editing (even basic) can be done.

Would love to just be able to check out / download a single file (file locked while checked out), edit it, then commit that edit and unlock the file again for other devs' edits (ideally the whole process can be done via a web app UI or a desktop GUI). Similar to the FTP system I'm so familiar with, but with code changes being tracked/timestamped/audited automatically - and the ability to revert to an earlier file (or diff several versions).

For these purposes, I'm thinking is it really 100% necessary for each new user to clone the entire 30gb repo just to edit a 50kb CSS file or a JS? Can a centralized system avoid that and work in the way described above?

I'm looking at Beanstalk and Git, and open to other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: git is distributed, so you can not use it to meet the requirement of not checking out the entire repo to make one change. However, GitHub and possibly some other similar tools will let you edit a file through the web interface and create a commit in the origin repo that way.

Comment: thx @Sean can anyone else weigh in on what other tools allow single file edits via web or GUI - without downloading the whole repo? This will be so handy when on the road.

Comment: A distributed VCS like Git is ideal when you're on the road, as long as you have a reasonably recent clone on a laptop when you start your travels. What typically doesn't fly with a DVCS is file locking, but that's usually not a desirable feature for source files anyway.